# White area at bottom of home page after removing background image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, removing-whitespace

I have a simple problem that, most likely, will have a simple solution. I've checked other threads but none seem to properly fix the issue I'm having.

**My issue:** A white space at the bottom of my home page.

My goal is to have a page with a solid black background and a navbar at the top, where the black background covers the entire page and has no scroll bar. Currently I'm having trouble getting the body element to cover the height of the page in black, so instead I'm seeing a large white space underneath my page content.

I've tried messing with the margins and padding, but I think I may be doing it in the wrong location.

My site: [www.hallofheroclix.com](http://www.hallofheroclix.com) (colors will be all black at finish)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why are you not assigning black blackground color to body itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not assigned background color to body.

Please add background CSS property to body:

```
body {
    color: #141412;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked something so simple! That worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this instead**

I have looked you coding, i have made some changes to html structure and added some css.You can add / update  this css to your css file style.css.

**Css**
<style>
    .navbar {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgb(255, 242, 0);
      position: static !important;
      top: -230px;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100% !important;
    }
    .main-container {
      background-color: red;
      height: 301px;
    }
    #page {
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
    }
</style>

**Html**
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="Skip to content">Skip to content</a>
                    <div class="nav-menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="">BP</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-20 current_page_item"><a href="">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-24"><a href="">Test Subject</a></li></ul></div>
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
            </form>                 
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
            </header><!-- #masthead -->
            <div class="main-container">
             <a class="home-link" href="# title="My Site" rel="home">
                <h1 class="site-title">My Site</h1>
                <h2 class="site-description">Cool logo coming soon!</h2>
            </a>
           </div>
                <div id="main" class="site-main">
```